# git - Error when I update a repository

Tags: git, github, repository, synchronization

I have a repository cloned by github. Im trying to pull the last changes it using `git push origin master` but i get an error : [image]

How I can fix this?

EDIT: Problem found. My bad. I was using `git push` instead of `git pull`. Silly me :/

Comment: Can you give the output you get by typing git remote -v

Comment: origin  https://github.com/0xd4d/dnlib (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/0xd4d/dnlib (push)

Comment: Are you 0xd4d? Do you have write permission to this repository?

Comment: No I'm not. Ups bad title. I mean i want to update the repository with the last commits

Comment: So you want to pull the changes from the remote repository to your PC right?

Comment: Omg i found the problem.  Iam using push instead of pull. Yesterday i pulled a repository and after 2 minutes I couldnt and i was wondering why. I just found it. Thank you

Comment: Could you answer this topic with the solution so I can mark it as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were trying to pull the changes from the Github repository to your PC.

Use `git pull origin master` instead of `git push`

Answer (score 0):

2 options

- You are not the owner of the repository (you simply forked/cloned it) so you dont have aceess rights to teh repostiry
- You are the owner/collaborator but you did not set permissions to the user.

If you are the owner/collaborator its better to switch from https to ssh. Why? it will not ask you for password every time you do `fetch/pull/push`

---

#### Setting ssh key under github

Simply follow those steps and you will set up your ssh key in no time:

- Generate a new ssh key (or skip this step if you already have a key)
  `ssh-keygen -t -rsa -C "your@email"`
- Once you have your key set in `home/.ssh` directory (or `Users/<your user>.ssh` under windows), open it and copy the content

---

#### How to add sh key to github account?

- Login to github account
- Click on the rancher on the top right (Settings)
  [image: github account settigns]
- Click on the `SSH keys`
  [image: ssh key section]
- Click on the `Add ssh key`
  [image: Add ssh key]
- Paste your key and save

Now go to your repository and update the remote url to ssh inseatd of https.

---

#### How to change remote URL?

- Editing `.git/config` and replacing the url
- `git remote set-url origin <url>`

Comment: I still getting an error : Permission denied (publickey). Instead of my e-mail i used the (username)@users.noreply.github.com email. Maybe that causes a problem or something?

Comment: Copy the url from git hub and make sure that the project is forked to your account or that you are contributor to the project

Comment: Sorry problem found. I've just wanted to pull the changes and i was using `git push` instead of `git pull`

Comment: I really appreciate it but it wasn't the solution to my problem (even if my question was wrong) so I accepted the "correct" answer (not that yours wasn't correct). Sorry about that.